# Optimizing multiple video player objects in page via using JS to display video thumbnails+play buttons instead

Tags: javascript, django, azure-media-services

**Background:**
I'm developing a video-on-demand feature for a Django web application of mine. Most of my users are those using web on Android devices (in case that matters). At the moment, I'm using azure media player to display my videos (via adaptive bitrate streaming). Videos are served as a sorted list - up to 10 videos are shown per page. The template code is simply:

```
{% for vid in object_list %}
<video id="vid{{ forloop.counter }}" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls width="640" height="400" poster="{{ vid.low_res_thumb }}" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false },"language":"ur","nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
<source src="{{ vid.video_manifest }}" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
</video>
{% endfor %}
```

Rendering the video player directly like this is heavy. A better way is displaying a video thumbnail with a play icon placed over it (so that it looks like a video player), like so:

```
    <div style="width:640px; height:400px;background-image:url({{ vid.low_res_thumb }});background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: auto 100%;background-position: center;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/play_btn.png" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:20%;">
    </div>
```

In this approach, once the play button is hit, the video thumbnail is replaced with azure media player with `autoplay` so that the video plays instantly.

**Problem:**
I need to write a JS function that scans the page for videos, adding corresponding thumbnails+play_btns and an onclick event listener that replaces the image with the actual azure media player in autoplay mode. Being a JS beginner, I'm struggling to do this and need assistance.

Would it be something like:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var v = document.getElementsById("vid{{ forloop.counter }}");
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement("div");
        p.innerHTML = showThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = ???
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
})();

function showThumb(id) {
    return '<div style="width:640px; height:400px;background-image:url({{ vid.low_res_thumb }});background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: auto 100%;background-position: center;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/play_btn.png" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:20%;">
    </div>';
}
</script>
```

Need help in improving this. Specifically: (i) am I correctly referencing `getElementsById`, (ii) am I formulating `p.innerHTML` correctly, and (iii) how do I handle `p.onclick`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Below is example which is agnostic to any particular framework but i was using your notation from question.

Note that i am passing dom element itself and manifest uri to a javascript function. javascript function is initializing amp player by changing innerHtml and assigning id attribute to video tag from index variable. This variable is increasing while you clicking and playing video elements.You can modify this logic to have some other logic.

Once div tag with image  is clicked, I am removing onclick handler in order to allow player intercept on click events.

```
{% for vid in object_list %}
<div onclick="myFunction(this, {{ vid.video_manifest }})" >
     <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}" witdh="640" height="400">
</div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
var index = 0;

function myFunction(element, manifestUri){
index++;
element.innerHTML ="<video id=\"azuremediaplayer" + index + "\" class=\"azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered\" tabindex=\"0\"> </video>";
var myOptions = {
            autoplay: true,
            controls: true,
            width: "640",
            height: "400",
            poster: ""
        };
        var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer"+index, myOptions);
        myPlayer.src([{ src: manifestUri , type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" }, ]);
         element.removeAttribute("onclick");
}        
    </script>
```

Please note that auto-play is not supported for mobile devices - see https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/known_issues.htm. 
Script above will serve as  optimization for desktop clients.
You can detect mobile users and do full rendering of video html tags for each element in a loop and initialize azure media player for each video dom element like below:

```
<script>

function myFunction(id, manifestUri){

var myOptions = {
            autoplay: true,
            controls: true,
            width: "640",
            height: "400",
            poster: ""
        };
        var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer"+id, myOptions);
        myPlayer.src([{ src: manifestUri , type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" }, ]);


}        
    </script>

{% for vid in object_list %}
```

```
<script>myfunction('{{ vid.video_id }}','{{ vid.video_manifest }}');</script>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can find example with static html  here https://jsfiddle.net/gtrifonov/g1q9ojxo/3/

Comment: On desktop if you tried solution in jsfiddler users need to click just once, when autoplay option is set to true( tested in chrome,edge, ie11). As you mention for mobile users you can detect if it is a mobile user and  essentially skip optimization. In your for loop do proper rendering video html tag and js initialization of Azure media player for each video . It should not affect performance a lot, if you have some sort of paging and generating 10-30 items at a time.

Comment: For reference: auto-play restriction in mobile described at https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/known_issues.html

Comment: Majority of my users are on mobile, and on slow networks - i.e. patchy 3G and mostly choked bandwidth. Now the azure media player will need to be loaded from the internet, so I was thinking it would be a *faster* experience if I just called each browser's native html5 video player instead, and used a `progressive download` encoded video served from AMS (instead of adaptive).

And then, the JS I'd write would simply be to offer download buttons to those ladies and gentlemen who can't stream .mp4 files.

Comment: This works as well. You can also form proper HLS manifest link to play progressive on devices with HLS support. see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services-extensions/blob/bfbf9ef111f0bb71f6906dab7bcdc61432b3dd1a/MediaServices.Client.Extensions.Tests/ILocatorExtensionsFixture.cs how to form link for appropriate hls version. IOS will play progressive encoded video natively.

Comment: Actually the problem with these .ism urls is that preferred browsers of my target userbase (e.g. Opera, UC Browser) don't run m3u8 (btw iOS is not a core use case, Android much more core for me). Overall, I feel for users on low-end Androids in low bandwidth conditions, using proxy browsers like Opera, the best bet is to remain with progressive + native player. Adaptive is great tech, but the compatibility isn't amazing among my kind of demographics. Btw, my demographic is mostly South Asian semi-rural people buying low-end smartphones. I want to serve them a basic VoD feature, powered by AMS.